# Some questions on C language (C89)

Tags: c

Sorry for my English.

Below I listed questions answers on which I look for for C language (C89).

1. How can I get processors count?
2. How can I get processor cores count?
3. How can I get processor name?
4. How can I get RAM size?
5. How to learn level of loading of this or that processor (or core)?

Regards

Comment: Those questions have nothing to do with the C language.

Comment: Can't do any of those in pure C, you need OS specific code.

Comment: cat /proc/cpu answers most of your question. why bother to another  application?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need an OS API.
2. You need an OS API.
3. You need an OS API.
4. You need an OS API.
5. You need an OS API.

Comment: -1 for not specifyng the names , OP could have started with his work.

Comment: @CyprUS: What names are you talking about??

Comment: like GetSystemInfo - that gives the number of processors etc.

Comment: @CyprUS What are you talking about? `$ man -S2 GetSystemInfo` yields 
“No manual entry for `GetSystemInfo`”

Comment: @CyprUS: I was talking about the need for "_an_ OS API". You speak about a specific one, as if there was "_the_ OS API". There isn't however, and I am not aware of the OS C originally was developed for having a sys call `GetSystemInfo()`. ICBWT.

Comment: @CyprUS: Many operating systems are written in language C. And API as is written on C. I want to understand, how by means of this language information specified by me was received for OS API.